# PHP + MYSQL Storing urls , what column type and strategy should be used

Tags: php, mysql

For a webscraper I will store 5 million+ full urls in a table.
I will need to check if the url does not exist in the table very often.

What column type and strategy is best for performance?

- url with varchar and an index.

Or

- second char column with an hash ( md5?) and check for that.

Or a completely different strategy ?

Comment: Second. You can store raw hash (binary) which takes up half the space. For MD5 that'd be 16 bytes, so `BINARY(16)` is fine.

Comment: Either way you'll want an index on it if you're going to query it.

Comment: Id probably have a column with the primary domain like e.g: example.com and have it as a index to reduce query times to find paths stored on that domain.

Comment: @Accountantم primary key on a text column with unknown max length? No, it wouldn't be the easiest way. It's the worst thing you can do. Literally, *the worst*. And the idea with primary domain and what not.. guys, it's 5 million records only, don't try to reinvent the wheel. Just index the hash of the column. A machine with 2 gb of RAM available for MySQL will eat this up even with full table scans..

Comment: @N.B. I'm sorry I removed the comment before your comment, Yes you are right a hashed URL as a primary key may be easier, I just thought it will add some cost for hashing every time you need to select or store.

Answer (score 2):

Second option. If you need to check if url doesn't exist, then a `unique` constraint on the hash of the URL is optimal method.

`md5`, even though dated, is ok for your use case as you have ~5 million rows, it's not likely you'd get a collision.

For the column, use `BINARY(16)`. You can store `UNHEX(MD5('your url here'));` into `BINARY(16)`, having fixed index length.

`md5` is 128 bits, you don't need human-readable representation so you can save the "raw" binary which lets you cut the storage requirements in half - hence `BINARY(16)` instead of `BINARY(32)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot N.B.  , you are saying md5 is dated, which hash would you consider a better one for an url?  I am open for all options.  The thing I care about is performance.  Also...   Would it be better to do a md5 encode in php before ( md5($url,true) >> gives binary 16 )  or just do it raw in mysql.

Comment: I'd create a trigger that calculates the hash in MySQL, and I'd create a `before insert` and `before update` one. `md5`. You can keep `md5` if you're after performance, to get a collision you need A LOT more data than you have at your disposal.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum width of an index is 767 bytes - but IIRC there is no upper limit on the size of a URL. This is rather long even for a URL. OTOH, the longer the data, the more work the DBMS has to do in order to compare 2 values.

Hence using a hash is probably not required but will enhance performance.

Some mysql engines support an index type of 'hash' which avoids the need to create a new column (but I don't think this is supported on MyISAM and InnoDB). OTOH recent versions of MySQL (and MariaDB, PerconaDB) support "[generated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/generated-column-index-optimizations.html)" or virtual columns. So you don't need to explicitly set the value for the hash when inserting/updating (but you would need to use `table.hashed=MD5('$yourURL')` in the WHERE clause to allow the DBMS to use the index.

Personally, if it were me, I'd be concerned about indexing the same page twice under different URLs - particularly where the query changes:

```
 http://www.example.com/?r=32323
```

and

```
 http://www.example.com/?r=51515
```

might refer to different content or may be the same - I'd also consider keeping a hash of the content.

Comment: thanks for your answer symcbean. I will look into this.Starting with a blank slate  , what would be your strategy to store (let's say ) 10 million urls in a table that need a fast EXIST return ?

Comment: Don't check. Use a unique index and check the error message if the insert fails. 1 query instead of 2